# Deleting Database entries and associated Junction table data in MYSQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

A have a situation where Lessons are created, teachers are assigned to teach said lessons, and students can then book them. These are both many to many. Lesson <-> Teachers and Lesson<->Students. There is a lesson table and two junction tables linking them.

Here is the structure:

```
Lesson Table - lesson.lessonID
Lesson/Student Junction Table - lsj.lessonFK 
Lesson/Teacher Junction Table - ltj.lessonFK
```

I'm looking to delete a lesson from the lessons table but can't because of the junction table associations. I've tried deleting the associations first and then the lesson but it doesn't seem to work.

```
DELETE
FROM junc_lesson_teacher, junc_lesson_student, lesson
JOIN user ON user.userID = junc_lesson_teacher.teacherFK
JOIN lesson ON lesson.lessonID = junc_lesson_teacher.lessonFK
WHERE lessonID = {$id}//PHP $_GET id from a form
```

What is the best way to go about deleting a lesson with teacher and student associations?
Thanks for any input!

EDIT:

I've also tried sending this as a query but it doesn't seem to work:

```
DELETE FROM junc_lesson_teacher WHERE junc_lesson_teacher.lessonFK = {$id};
DELETE FROM junc_lesson_student WHERE junc_lesson_student.lessonFK = {$id};
DELETE FROM lesson WHERE lesson.lessonID = {$id};
```

Comment: What I understood from the above query is that you want to delete the records from the Lesson table and its associated entry from the student and teacher table.

So I guess you need to first delete the records from the Student and teacher table and then delete the record from Lesson table

Comment: Basically what I thought too, however the query didn't work... See edit.

Comment: Can you specify the error that you get??

Answer (score 0):

That query can be executed successfully if you will alter the foreign key behavior of your tables. Go to this [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) and take not of these keywords below in the CREATE TABLE statement. This also has other variants in ON DELETE NO ACTION and ON DELETE SET NULL, among others that I may have not known yet.

> ON DELETE CASCADE

This is also applicable with an ALTER TABLE statement if you have built your schema already. But be careful because once you deleted a row that has many associated foreign key relationships with other tables. Those rows are also deleted from other tables.